# Add extra items to a cookie and grab them? Asp.net MVC C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When checking for a users role in my custom authorize tag I am going to need a 3rd value. Like the built in stuff allows for this

"filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;"

But this won't work for me since I will have many users with the same name. So I don't think this will help me when I have 10 with the same name and I have to pull up the GUID from them.

When doing my login stuff I use another field to tell the users apart.

So I am wondering can I show that 3rd field in the cookie(or however it does it with User.Identity.Name) and encrypt it with the cookie so it is safe and then do something like

"filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.UnquieField;"

Comment: What exactly do you need in the cookie?  What are the 1st and 2nd values?

Comment: Sorry it should be 2nd(thinking of when you log in and the 3rd would be password) value. The 1st value is Username and 2nd value is just some preifx I give to users from the same group. It allows me to have many groups so by looking at prefiex and userName I can have duplicate userName but still know who they are. As long as the prefix is different the same UserName can be used. If the prefix is used and the userName is used then that name is rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when I need to store multiple values into a cookie I create a lightweight class and use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) to serialize/deserialize the class into the cookie's value.  Therefore your cookie would look something like this:

> user={UserName:bob123,Prefix:group1}

You can format it however you like, however.  If Json is too heavy you could do something as simple as "user=bob123,group1".

The important thing is that your controller is going to need logic to parse/unparse the username and prefix from/to the cookie's value.

Comment: How do I add it to the cookie? Is this what User.Identity.Name does? This parsing would happen for me in my customAttribute.

Comment: I am using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie by the way. So not sure do I have to make it another way to do this?